# Scroll two colums until last element is reached

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I want to create a feed page similar to [**LinkedIn**](https://www.linkedin.com/feed/). The behavior I want is `two` cols side by side first col has lots of elements while the second one has fewer elements. When the user scrolls both of the cols are scrolled. But once the bottom-most element is reached, it gets stiched to view. Now on further scrolling, only first col elements are scrolled. When we scroll up the second col also gets scrolled up.
I am using angular and typescript to make this.
Few reference images are attached below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Edit:**
I am trying to do this using bootstrap rows and cols

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-4" style="position:fixed;">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What did you try so far ? What is your actual behavior we can help you on ?

Comment: @Random I tried making the position of contents on the second col fixed. This made them stick to the view but not scrollable.

Comment: Can you show your relevant HTML/CSS code, so we can see how to change it to make it work ?

Comment: @Random I added code also.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: sticky; bottom: 0` on the second column. Quick example:

```css
.col2 { position: sticky; bottom: 0; margin-left: 50px; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col1">
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
    <p>col 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col2">
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
    <p>col 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey this acrually works. But how to do this using bootstrap row and cols. Thanks!

Comment: It's not working if I don't include margin-left: 50px;

Comment: This quick solution doesn't work with Bootstrap rows and columns. You'd just have to change the structure, so there is a single "main-content" element and a "sidebar" element with manual sizing instead of BS cols.

Comment: Is this responsive?

Comment: If you make it responsive, it will be. e.g. use percentages and @media declarations. I just gave a solution to the question before knowing you were using Bootstrap.